# Remove right default shadow in android Button

Tags: android, xml, button, background, shadow

i want to remove default right shadow in a `Button` but i don't know how to do it, i tried also to set his background transparent, but it didn't work. 
I'll post here my code and what i'm getting now.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:background="@drawable/search_rounded" <!-- drawable background with blue gradient-->
    android:padding="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Latest Chapters"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#0361c9"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/backToTopBtn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/backToTopBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded" <!--white background with rounded corners-->
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Back to top"
        android:id="@+id/backToTopBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/> <!--setting right button's background transparent-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I want to remove that shadow line between textview and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: @JoanColmenero i know, i just waited the 8 minutes!